# making Linq case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using vs 2010 with linq to sql and sql server 2008. how would i made this case sensitive

```
  var Groups = from gp in _db.Groups 
               where gp.vcr_GroupName == GroupName 
               select gp;
```

here `groupname=abc` and `groupname=ABC` is same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming GroupName is a string, you can do a simple string comparison and ignore case:

```
var Groups = from gp in _db.Groups 
             where gp.vcr_GroupName.Equals(GroupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
             select gp;
```

Comment: Exception:  `"Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL."`

Answer (score 2):

That's not a point for a linq query.

It's a setting within the sql server 2008. Microsoft Sql Server 2008 handles string comparisons by default case invariant.

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141038.aspx

Answer (score 2):

use the `SqlMethods.Like` that **[is case Sensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx)** and available for SQL.

```
 where System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(gp.vcr_GroupName, GroupName)
```