# how to compare string in lambda expression

Tags: c#, string, lambda, comparison

I have an issue that I would appreciate any help with.

Background - I have a database that holds a string (i.e. - StackOverFlow) and I need to compare a passed in value to that string and make it case sensitive.

Right now I have a connection to the database (using EF 4), an `IRepo<T>` interface (which I use to access the table) and a `FindAllMatching` method that returns an `IQueryable<table>` and takes in an `Expression<Func<tableName, bool>> expression` parameter.

Repo class:

```
public class TableRepo : IRepo<table>{
  private EF4Entity _dc = new EF4Entity();
  public IQueryable<table> FindAllMatching(Expression<Func<table, bool>> expression)
  {
    return _dc.table.Where(expression);
  }
}
```

Calling Code:

```
public class CallingClass
{
  public void CallingMethod(string enteredStringFromTextBoxOnFrontEnd)
  {
    var tableDB = new TableRepo();
    var returnValue = tableDB.FindAllMatching(x => x.ColumnInTableThatHoldsString.CompareTo(enteredStringFromTextBoxOnFrontEnd) ==0);
  }
}
```

Right now, when I pass in a string that matches what is in the table in every way but in case (stackoverflow as opposed to StackOverFlow) the `returnValue` actually returns a row from the table.  If the value that is passed in doesn't match the value contained in the database table exactly, I want it to return null or a count of zero.

I have tried doing `.Equals(enteredStringFromTextBoxOnFrontEnd, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` and all the other `StringComparison` values and nothing compares case.

If you need more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq To Sql uses the database compare rules.

You need to add an extra IEnumerable.Where at the end to do a local filtering of the result

```
var returnValue = (ItableDB.FindAllMatching(x => x.ColumnInTableThatHoldsString == enteredStringFromTextBoxOnFrontEnd) as IEnumerble<TableRepo>).Where(x => x.ColumnInTableThatHoldsString == enteredStringFromTextBoxOnFrontEnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that this is not an issue with your code but with your database.  I'm presuming that you're using some flavour of SQL Server.  By default when you install SQL Server it is case insensitive on all text queries.

You might want to see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416254/making-linq-case-sensitive) for possible answers.