# How to do a case sensitive LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am using a LINQ query to retrieve product SKUs. The problem is that `lgVM670VG` is different from `lgVM670Vg`; the query will return the result no matter what (the actual SKU is `lgVM670VG`).

```
SKU currentSKU = new SKU();
SKUDataContext dcSKU = new SKUDataContext();
var skuQuery =
    (from s in dcSKU.SKUs
     where s.SKU1 == strSKU
     orderby s.SKU1
     select s).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Duplicate found by following search - http://www.bing.com/search?q=case+insensitive+linq+sql

Comment: _"The problem is that `...G` is different from `...g`"_ - so you want a case **sensitive** search. See @Johnny5's answer, set the proper collation, or see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5416339/266143) in [making Linq case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416254/making-linq-case-sensitive), the duplicate mentioned here is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to set a case sensitive collation on your sql server.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison) for examle.